# Finding all events happening at a specific hour

Tags: sql, schedule

I have a database of events and I want to make a daily schedule of it.
It looks something as following:

```
+-----+-----+---+--------+  
|Event|Start|End|Duration|  
+-----+-----+---+--------+    
|A    |08   |10 |2       |  
+-----+-----+---+--------+  
|B    |09   |10 |1       |  
+-----+-----+---+--------+    
|C    |13   |15 |2       |  
+-----+-----+---+--------+
```

I want to query for all events that are held at 9 and I can't figure the math behind calculating the time.
The query should return A and B for this example. I tried:
start + duration > 9 and start <=9 but it isn't correct...

Any help please?

Comment: If you tried `WHERE start + duration > 9 and start <=9` then you're already tried what @GordonLinoff suggested *(because `start+duration` matches `end` in your example)*.  So, what was your actual sql for your attempt, and exactly what didn't work?  *(error message, wrong results, what, exactly?)*

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Don't store numeric values as string...  In string comparisons `09` comes before `8`, because it compares the character one at a time in order *(and `0` comes before `8`)*.  Use integers, for pity's sake...

Comment: I guess the problem was the strings. Thank you. I am not using any database, just trying to learn some SQL with a small project.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this `where` clause:

```
where start <= 9 and end > 9
```

That is, something happens at 9 if it starts one or before 9 and ends after 9.  (If you want things that end at 9 to be included, just change the `>` to `>=`).

I notice that you have leading zeros.  This suggests that the values are stored as strings.  In that case, do string comparisons:

```
where start <= '09' and end > '09'
```

Comment: Thank you and for the quick reply :)